# Deduce format specifier from data type?

Tags: c, types, printf, format-specifiers

Is it possible to deduce the format specifier programmatically for a data type? For instance if the print is for a long it automatically does something like:

```
printf("Vlaue of var is <fmt_spec> ", var);
```

I also feel it would reduce some errors on part of developer since something like

```
printf("Name is %s",int_val); //Oops, int_val would be treated as an address

printf("Name is %s, DOB is",name,dob); // missed %d for dob

printf("Name is %s DOB is %d", name);//Missed printing DOB
```

I understand that the latter two do have warnings but wouldn't it be better if errors were thrown since in most cases it is going to be problematic? Or am I missing something or are there constructs already in place to do so ?

Comment: Some compilers (GCC, Clang) issue warnings for mismatched formats and arguments. But to answer your question: No it's not really possible. C doesn't have built-in capabilities of [introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) or [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)). You can not in a standard way get the types of data at run-time.

Comment: Also, with GCC and Clang you can easily turn specific warnings into errors. Or turn *all* warnings into errors, and then disable the errors for specific warnings.

Comment: Format specifiers aren't just for types. E.g. `%o` and `%x` both take `unsigned int`; `%e`, `%f`, `%g` all take `double`; `%d`, `%i`, `%c` all take `int`. That's why you can't (in general) deduce them from the arguments.

Comment: Because the programmer creates the variables, the programmer is expected to know the type of the variable, and thus the responsibility lies with the caller. There is no nice programmatic way to deal with format specifiers.

Comment: If it was possible, why would C require to do it manually?

Comment: In theory it is possible.  I believe it can be done using variadic templates and constexpr format string scanning.  Not a simple task, for dubious gains, but it is possible.  If you are really concerned about type-correctness,you should use streams.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy The question is about C.

Comment: "They do have warnings". C does not have any cocoon, that comes from the OS and from useful but not obligitary compiler warnings. Other languages might help you more, but C is brutally efficient.

Comment: `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wpedantic -Werror …` et voila! Life would be so much safer if the producers of firearms would not drill that long hole in the barrels. Oh, wait, then these things would not make sense …

Comment: @Olaf [Good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662078/deduce-format-specifier-from-data-type/44663207?noredirect=1#comment76311822_44662078), yet that will not warn about `printf("%hhd, some_int);` as sub-`int/unsigned` print specifiers match all `int/unsigned`.

Comment: @chux: Yes, it was a shot in the dark. It warns about UB, though. If one tends to shoot his feet, he should not wear a gun. IOW: C is not a language for uncautious people. Hence my nit-picking. Nevertheless, one should not try to make C a different language. Macros are useful, but if getting too fancy with them one eventually ends in macro hell. Maybe all beginners have to cross that river - the better ones accept advice, the mediocre (or those which don't get this advice) do it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Deduce format specifier from data type?

*No*.

As melpomene stated:

"Format specifiers aren't just for types. E.g. `%o` and `%x` both take `unsigned int`; `%e`, `%f`, `%g` all take `double`; `%d`, `%i`, `%c` all take `int`. That's why you can't (in general) deduce them from the arguments."

Point is that if such a functionality existed, then would it deduce `unsiged int` to `%o` or `%x`, for example? And so on . . .

---

About whether some cases should issue a warning or an issue, you should think about how casting works in [c](/questions/tagged/c), and when it does make sense to allow something or not. In GCC, you could of course treat warning(s) as error(s):

```
-Werror
Make all warnings into errors.

-Werror=
Make the specified warning into an error. The specifier for a warning is appended; for example -Werror=switch turns the warnings controlled by -Wswitch into errors. This switch takes a negative form, to be used to negate -Werror for specific warnings; for example -Wno-error=switch makes -Wswitch warnings not be errors, even when -Werror is in effect.

The warning message for each controllable warning includes the option that controls the warning. That option can then be used with -Werror= and -Wno-error= as described above. (Printing of the option in the warning message can be disabled using the -fno-diagnostics-show-option flag.)

Note that specifying -Werror=foo automatically implies -Wfoo. However, -Wno-error=foo does not imply anything.
```

as you can read [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to deduce the format specifier programmatically  for a data type?

Not easily nor directly with `printf()`, yet...

Yes, with limitations to a select set of types, by using of `_Generic`.

This could be done various ways and used with `*printf()` with great dificulty, yet I found a similar approach to print data, without specifying individual format specifiers in this example:
[Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers using _Generic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485)
Note: This code has a coding hole concerning pointer math, that I have since patched - though not posted.

```
GPrintf("Name is ", GP(name), " is ", GP(dob), GP_eol);
```

The key was to use `_Generic(parameter)` to steer the selection of the code used to convert the type to text by having the macro `GP(x)` expand to 2 parts: a string and `x`.  Then  `GPrintf()` interprets the arguments.
This is akin to [@Michaël Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662078/deduce-format-specifier-from-data-type/44663207#comment76310026_44662078)'s comment, yet staying in C rather than C++.

Comment: There is a defect report about `_Generic`. Some interpretation would be left to the implementation. It also will not work as it should with e.g. `size_t` which is a `typedef` to a standard type, but uses a distinct conversion type specifier.

Comment: @Olaf Concerning "`size_t` which is a `typedef`" can be handled with levels of `_Generic`.  E.g. Top level uses `unsigned, unsigned, long, unsigned long long` and `default`.  `default` uses and 2nd level _Generic_ which has `size_t`.  This does not always provide the `z`, yet allows code to distinguish if it is important.  IOWs a _comparable_ specifier can be had.

Comment: Please read 6.5.1.1p2: "… No two generic associations in the same generic selection shall specify compatible types …" - do you disagree the alias `typedef unsigned int size_t;` is compatible with `unsigned int`? Read the report; there are more problems. It explicitly lists clang and gcc as non-identical implementations. Apart from this: That's way too much obfuscation for a non-existent problem. C is statically typed, all types are known at compile-time and printing typically uses known types. Special output needs additional care (as the linked examples show). Solution looking for problem.

Comment: @Olaf I was not suggesting  `size_t` and `unsigned` in the same generic selection - but at different levels. Terse example:  `#define info2(X) _Generic((X), \
    size_t: "z", \
    default: "?" \
)


#define info(X) _Generic((X), \
  unsigned long long: "ull", \
  unsigned long: "ul", \
  unsigned: "u", \
  default: info2(X) \
  )

int main() {
  size_t sz;
  puts(info(sz));
  unsigned u;
  puts(info(u));
}`

Comment: Ok, that might work. But what if `size_t` is a compiler-additional type. gcc for instance defines a lot of internal types and macros to keep the headers more clean (e.g. `INT_MIN` etc are defined that way). Honestly: do you really recommend all this? If you only have a hammer, every problem looks like a nail. Some problems just don't work well with a hammer. And itf there is a lot of output, dynamic languages like Python are definitively the better choice.

Comment: @Olaf The [2 level idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662078/deduce-format-specifier-from-data-type/44663207?noredirect=1#comment76313547_44663207) would certainly work with "`size_t` is a compiler-additional type".  Levels can be added if needed.  GTG

Comment: … making the whole macro hell implementtion-specific. Wasn't exactly **that** the thing to avoid? Too fancy, indeed.